# Alternating row colours in terminal

Tags: shell, terminal

Is there any terminal or shell that supports alternating row colours for better readability? Commands that output data in table form, for example apt-cache search, is sometimes a bit hard to read, especially for wide terminal windows, and it would be easier if odd-numbered row were slightly differently coloured than even-numbered rows.

Comment: you can try `lolcat` - https://github.com/busyloop/lolcat

Comment: @Rabin haha nice idea :) Use with flags like `lolcat -p 100000 -F 1` or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look for a terminal emulator that supports background image in tiling (i.e. repeated, not scaled/stretched) mode, and create such a background image for yourself.

The main drawback is that it won't work if you zoom the terminal, but it could work great if you have a certain favorite font size that you always use.

Don't forget about the padding of the terminal. E.g. in case of VTE-based emulators (and many others) there's a default padding of 1px around the whole area of character cells. If your font height is let's say 20px, you should create a 1x40 picture with the topmost pixel being color1, then 20 pixels of color2, then another 19 pixels of color1. This is, of course, assuming the emulator aligns the background image at the top.

Among the terminal emulators based on recent version of VTE, Terminix [update: it's now called Tilix] and Xfce4-terminal (version 0.8.x) support background images, you should give them a try to see if they offer this kind of tiling. If not, I'm pretty sure their authors would be open to implementing this (just point them to this page :)). Older versions of VTE used to explicitly support background image, but I don't recommend using that due to plenty of other bugs. Terminology and urxvt are a few other possibilities to try.

I used to have a permanent right margin at column 80 using this approach.

Update: I've actually tried it with xfce4-terminal and it works kind of as expected. One small drawback I didn't think of is that the background doesn't scroll along with the content when you scroll back, which is especially disturbing with the (IMO otherwise cool) per-pixel scrolling of VTE-0.44.

Answer (score 3):

You can pipe the output of the things you want to colorize to a little awk script, it should not hinder performance too much. For instance:

```
NR%2 == 0 {
    print "\033[1;36m" $0 "\033[0m"
    next
}

{
    print "\033[1;46;30m" $0 "\033[0m"
}
```

1. Put this in a `.awk` file somewhere in your `PATH`
2. Add this line to your `.bashrc` and re-source it:

   ```
   alias ImFabulous='myfunc';myfunc(){ eval "$@ | awk -f MakeItFabulous.awk";}
   ```
3. Try: `$ ImFabulous <your command here>`.

For example: `ImFabulous cat /etc/hosts`. The version I gave is pretty basic, but for your large tabulated files it should do the trick. You can temper with it by looking up the [color escape sequences](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x329.html) to fit your type of fabulous. If you don't want the alias, you can just type this: `<my command> | awk -f MakeItFabulous.awk`

Comment: Just put `#!/usr/bin/awk -f` as the first line in the Awk script and make it executable. No need for the `eval` or a shell function that way. And seriously, an alias calling a shell function!?

Comment: Why not, it works right ? Okay, your way is probably more logical. But yeah, an alias calling a function can be useful though.

Comment: Just make a function, if you think you need one. The alias is a no-op. Also, the `eval` is _not needed_.  `awk -f script.awk "$@"` will do just nicely. The next step is to ditch the shell function and instead just use the executable script, as I mentioned. Out of the three steps (alias, function, script), only the last is ever needed here.

Comment: Additionally, having the shell function call the script requires it to be in the current directory. Putting the Awk script in your `PATH` will not help.